# Keeping a XMPP connection alive or (re)connect on activity start up

Tags: android, service, xmpp, keep-alive, messenger

I'm currently working on an application that uses *asmack* [source](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) to connect to a XMPP Server. This application basically includes all the default messenger attributes (Sending/receiving messages, changing statuses, etc).

At the moment the `XMPP connection` lives inside the application and isn't in some sort of background service. So now I'm wondering, is it better to keep the connection alive using a service or just keeping the connection alive when my application is actually running.

This is taking in consideration that I **don't** want to stay connected to the XMPP Server the entire time (like days, or anything longer than half an hour) since this places a small but noticeable stress on the server.

So in a way I'm asking if it's better to (re)connect/log-in as soon as my Activity is brought to the foreground/started or is it better to connect once inside a service and just keep this connection alive?*(and possibly popping notifications on new incoming messages)*

Thanks in advance,